# JW Player does not work on Firefox not playing MP4 videos

Tags: flash, firefox, video

I am trying to use JW player so that it can play MP4 videos on Firefox but the problem is that it does not playing MP4 on firefox on the other hand it correctly working on Chrome and IE9 here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jw player</title>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/gQaACr0fEeKPFCIACqoQEQ.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='my-video'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4',
        image: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
        width: '640',
        height: '360'
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me it does play the video but blacked out a significant portion of it http://i.imgur.com/F1aWi4v.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this issue which I fixed by re-encoding the mp4.

In this particular instance I used [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to re-encode the mp4 using the default settings. Do NOT click the 'web optimised' check box as this seems to give the firefox behaviour you describe.